# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to SELECT data from 1 database and insert into another, but I have problem in INSERT.

I get this error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean` when I run my code.

**MY CODE**

```
<?php
include 'db_acc.php'; 
include 'db_sat.php'; 

$sql = "SELECT created_at,updated_at
        FROM satellite1.show_activity";
$result=$conn1->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "$row[updated_at]"; // I can get the value
    
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO analysis_account.currency SET
            id=0,
            currency_code='MYR',
            currency_rate= 3.500,
            currency_unit= 100,
            base_currency= 1,
            created_by= 2,
            updated_by= 2,
            created_at= '2021-05-17 14:10:32',
            updated_at = ".$row["updated_at"].", // But I cant insert the value
            curr_hidden = 1 ";

$query=$conn2->query($sql2);

}
$conn2->close();
?>
```

The problem is I can get the value of `$row[updated_at]` but I cant insert it into other database table, the connection is no problem because if I change `$row[updated_at]` into `'2021-05-17 14:10:32'` then the insert statement work.

I checked my connection, column names, symbols there are no problem of them. I really dont know what to do to solve the error.

Comment: Maybe a typo? $conn2 instead of $conn1?

Comment: Your code doesn't call `execute()`, so how can the error be generated here?

Comment: Nope, I checked it already, I can insert value by simply change ```$row[updated_at] ```into ```'2021-05-17 14:10:32'``` so i think it wont be typo

Comment: @NigelRen I used```$query=$conn2->query($sql2);``` this will execute the $sql so I dont need to call execute().

Comment: You should be using prepared statements anyway - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: My point was that your error doesn't match your code!  Sometimes changing the code can make the error not reproducible and therefore can waste others time.  If the code calls a function which wraps the error, then please include that as well as it may be the cause of the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `INSERT` query is missing quotes around the timestamp value. Just change

```
updated_at = ".$row["updated_at"].",
```

to

```
updated_at = '".$row["updated_at"]."',
```

This would fix the insert functionality but your code remains susceptible to SQL injection attacks. Please avoid simple string concatenation in your SQL queries and prefer *prepared statements* with placeholders.